# keep session variable after page load in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to keep the selected value in a drop down box after page reloads by creating session but i am not sure if my logic works because the drop down is not keeping the selected value before the refreshed.:
here is what i have:

```
string txtDDLLocation = ddlLocation.SelectedValue;
Session["MySessionVar"] = txtDDLLocation;
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
ddlLocation.SelectedValue = (string)Session["MySessionVar"];
```

Comment: In which event do you written this?

Comment: Can you show code with corresponding page names/method names? Clearly what you show now have no chance of working as you perform redirect and than do something that will have no effect on page you are navigating to.

Comment: Murali, not sure i am following your question, can u clarify please?

Comment: Your code is in page_load event or in ddl_change event ?

Comment: Just a suggestion but would it not be more efficient to just use a hidden field for this that you can update before each pageload (and instead of using reposnse.redirect() you can call pageload() or have the drop down list postback on selected value changed then during the page load event make the hidden field value the selected value of the drop down, ask if you want some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `ddlLocation.SelectedValue = (string)Session["MySessionVar"]` after `Response.Redirect`

Make sure you load the value in page_load event

```
protected void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(Session["MySessionVar"]!=null)
   ddlLocation.SelectedValue = (string)Session["MySessionVar"]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Lol setting session after redirect the code wil never reach the session variabele

Comment: Stefan, i was not sure if that was the case, but what other option i have in this case?

Comment: Place it before you come back to this page same as the answhere from murali